Why is my SlickJS carousel disappearing from my page?
I want to have a carousel of my reviews using slick.js (not need the style of slick so I don't include it on html header). When I try it the reviews-container disappears. How to fix it? What I'm doing wrong?
I want the result be like the image:

My HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>slick test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Customer Reviews Section -->
        <section class="reviews" aria-labelledby="reviews-heading">
            <div class="reviews-header" >
                <h2 id="reviews-heading">Our Happy Customers</h2>
                <div class="arrows-container">
                    <button><img src="./assets/images/arrow-left.svg" alt="left arrow" class="slick-prev" /></button>
                    <button><img src="./assets/images/arrow-right.svg" alt="right arrow" class="slick-next"/></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reviews-container">
                <div>
                    <article class="reviews-item">
                        <div class="rating">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                        </div>
                        <h3>Moora S. <span class="verified"><img src="./assets/images/verified.svg"></span></h3>
                        <p>"Shopping at Shop.co has been a game-changer for me. The fit and quality of the clothes are unmatched, and their customer service is always helpful!"</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <article class="reviews-item">
                        <div class="rating">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                        </div>
                        <h3>Sarah M. <span class="verified"><img src="./assets/images/verified.svg"></span></h3>
                        <p>"I'm blown away by the quality and style of the clothes I received from Shop.co. From casual wear to elegant dresses, every piece I've bought has exceeded my expectations."</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <article class="reviews-item">
                        <div class="rating">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                        </div>
                        <h3>Alex K. <span class="verified"><img src="./assets/images/verified.svg"></span></h3>
                        <p>"Finding clothes that align with my personal style used to be a challenge until I discovered Shop.co. The range of options they offer is truly remarkable, catering to a variety of tastes and occasions."</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <article class="reviews-item">
                        <div class="rating">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg"></div>
                        <h3>James L. <span class="verified"><img src="./assets/images/verified.svg"></span></h3>
                        <p>"As someone who's always on the lookout for unique fashion pieces, I'm thrilled to have stumbled upon Shop.co. The selection of clothes is not only diverse but also on-point with the latest trends."</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <article class="reviews-item">
                        <div class="rating">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg">
                            <img src="./assets/images/Star.svg"></div>
                        <h3>Moora S. <span class="verified"><img src="./assets/images/verified.svg"></span></h3>
                        <p>"Shopping at Shop.co has been a game-changer for me. The fit and quality of the clothes are unmatched, and their customer service is always helpful!"</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="newsletter">
    <h2>Stay up to date about our latest offers</h2>
    <form action="#" aria-label="Subscribe to Newsletter">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
      <button type="submit">Subscribe to Newsletter</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-content">
    <div class="brand">
      <h3>SHOP.CO</h3>
      <p>We have clothes that suit your style and which you're proud to wear. From women to men.</p>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="#" aria-label="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="#" aria-label="GitHub"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
      <div>
        <h4>Company</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Help</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Customer Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery Details</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>FAQ</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Manage Deliveries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Resources</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Free eBooks</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Development Tutorial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">How to - Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">YouTube Playlist</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-bottom">
    <p>&copy; Shop.co 2000-2023, All Rights Reserved</p>
    <div class="payment-options">
      <img src="visa-logo.png" alt="Visa">
      <img src="paypal-logo.png" alt="PayPal">
      <img src="apple-pay-logo.png" alt="Apple Pay">
      <img src="google-pay-logo.png" alt="Google Pay">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<!-- Include jQuery (required for Slick.js) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Slick JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Link to my External JavaScript -->
    
    <script src=".//reviews-slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

My CSS code
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
/* Customer Reviews Section */

.reviews {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.reviews-header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 6.25rem;
}

.reviews-container{
    display: flex;
    gap:20px;
}

.reviews-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Fixed width of 400px pixels */ ;
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 28px 32px;
}

.reviews-item p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.reviews-item h3 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
}


.nav-btn {
    background-color: #000; /* Button color */
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: #444; /* Darker color on hover */
}



/* General Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.newsletter {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.newsletter h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.newsletter form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.newsletter input[type="email"] {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.newsletter button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}

.footer-content .brand {
  flex: 1 1 250px;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer-content .brand h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-content .brand p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.social a {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 600px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.links div {
  text-align: left;
}

.links h4 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.links ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.links ul li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.links ul li a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.links ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-bottom p {
  flex: 1;
}

.payment-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.payment-options img {
  width: 50px;
}

/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .footer-content {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .links {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .newsletter form {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .newsletter input[type="email"] {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .footer-bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .payment-options {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .reviews-container {
        flex-direction: column; /* Stack reviews vertically on small screens */
    }

    .review {
        margin: 10px 0; /* Reduce margin for stacked layout */
    }
}

/* Accessibility */
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}

my Javascript code
// reviews carousel
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".reviews-container").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3, // Number of items visible at once
    slidesToScroll: 1, // Number of items scrolled per click
    arrows: true, // Enable navigation arrows
    prevArrow: $(".slick-prev"), // Use your custom prev arrow
    nextArrow: $(".slick-next"), // Use your custom next arrow
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768, // Responsive breakpoint
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2, // Adjust slidesToShow on smaller screens
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});


"not need the style of slick so I don't include it on html header" - Does including it correct the problem?  It may end up being easier to override styles where needed than to omit them entirely.

did you try it?
anyway doesn't work... something is going with the generated(by slick) divs and his widths and heights but don't know how to fix it

hmm.. the solution is actually quite simple.
Just give your .reviews-container a width of 100%.
oh and I really do recommend to anyhow import the slick css files, so you have a good starting point, you can always edit it afterwards.
Example on codepen can be found here: https://codepen.io/funkysoul/pen/PoMpvVa

To solve this problem you need to add heigh 100% to the 3 elements in the  slick carousel.

Change "article" to "h3" before
Add this code below after the end of your css code and will appear again:



/* Solutions */
.slick-list,
.slick-track,
.slick-slide h3 {
   height: 100%;   
}



Note: To keep using "article" instead of this "h3" you can do changes in the solution css code to adapt it.
Reference link: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/367

that you propose doesn't fix anything..
